# Change Axis for Historgram with PyPlot

Tags: python, matplotlib

Reading the documentation [here](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html), I need help limiting the histogram from 53 to 75.
First, I have the code,

```
plt.hist(d, bins=range(min(d), max(d) + binwidth, binwidth), label='diff', align='mid', normed=True, alpha = .8, color=colors[2])
plt.hist(s, bins=range(min(s)-1, max(s) + binwidth, binwidth), label='same', align='mid', normed=True, alpha = .5, color=colors[0])
```

which is fine in plotting this histogram [image].

However, I want to zoom in on the area above 53.  (Explicitly 53 to 75).  When I try this,

```
min_ = 53
plt.hist(d, bins=range(min_,75), label='diff', align='mid', normed=True, alpha = .8, color=colors[2])
plt.hist(s, bins=range(min_,75), label='same', align='mid', normed=True, alpha = .5, color=colors[0])
```

I instead of zooming in on the specified area, I zoom in and renorm the area.  The issue is tat I need to have the original normed area because the samples are very different sizes.  However when zooming in to the tail, I don't want to renorm the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `plt.axis()` function instead. For example:

```
plt.axis([53, 75, 0, .01])
```